# How to remux .dav files to mkv/mp4?

Tags: video-encoding

It's common for security video footage to be exported as .dav and this proprietary is useless for most people!

How can you remux it to mkv/mp4 without quality loss?

Answer (score 0):

To convert/remux lossless to mkv/mp4 you need a bunch of programs and follow some steps.

Software needed:

- [Intelbras Media Player](http://www.intelbras.com.br/empresarial/monitoramento/softwares-aplicativos/intelbras-media-player)
- [Mkvtoolnix (MKV)](https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html)
- [XMedia Recode (MP4)](https://www.xmedia-recode.de/en/download.html)

Then follow those steps:

1. Use Intelbras Media Player to export the file as `.avi`
2. Use mkvtoolnix to remux `.avi` to `.mkv` or use XMedia Recode with `copy` for
   `.mp4`

OBS: Intelbras is a Brazilian company and provides a free proprietary `.dav` software to export it as `.avi` files.

I find it to be more trustworthy than the random software you usually find on google when searching for this. They remux to `.avi` without quality loss. The software is available as english too.

The download button is next to the `exe` icon if you can't read portuguese (or use Google translate)

If people need more help with the GUI let me know and I'll update this. I did this because I thought google results for this search were too bad and wanted to share my knowledge.